# compilation error building an old version of R

Tags: r, compilation

In order to use a specific library that has not been updated for some time, I want to use an older version of R (2.3.1), under linux Mint 14.
I got the source file, installed the required library; checking with :

```
apt-cache showsrc r-base | grep Build-Depends
```

and issued, as indicated in the R-admin help page, the command:

```
./configue
```

that ended without error; then

```
make
```

that terminated with the following error message:

```
In file included from datetime.c:95:0:
Rstrptime.h:201:12: erreur: conflicting types for ‘wcsncasecmp’
In file included from ../../src/include/Defn.h:928:0,
             from datetime.c:58:
/usr/include/wchar.h:172:12: note: previous declaration of ‘wcsncasecmp’ was here
```

Does anyone know what trigered that error (conflicting type between files datetime.c and wchar.h, if I understand well), and how I could keep compiling past this error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that R 2.3.1 is very old, and was developed with the old C libraries in mind. With a recent linux install, you have the new C libraries which might not work well with your old R version. What you could do:

- Install an old version of linux from around the time of the R version, for example in a virtual machine.
- Port the package to the new version of R yourself.

The second option takes more time, but will make the work you base on the package more future proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; how could I do your second option ? By reconstructing the package ? Problem: there is a data file associated with the package, that is no longer recognized as a valid S4 object, and I have not the original data to reconstruct that object into a valid S4 object. Is there a procedure that could allow me to convert that obsolete S4 object to a valid S4 object compatible to the present version of R ?

Comment: I think it would be best to open a new question specifically for porting this package to a recent version of R. Do remember that you need the source version of the package to get this to work...

Comment: Thanks for your help; unfortunately, I don't have the source of this package; so I suppose the only way I am left with is to install an old version of linux in a virtual machine.

Comment: Just to come back to the original problem with the c lib; would it not be possible to install an old version in, say, the local/lib directory and indicate the location at compile time; would the c lib installed in such location disturb my system ?

Comment: You could install a local old version, but the amount of different libraries that you need old version of could be very big.